# Two sample $t$ test in R: where did it go wrong?

Tags: r, time-series, hypothesis-testing

I am doing two sampled t test on two species of fish.

```
t.test(fish1,fish2)
```

It runs for a year so there are 365 values for each fish, i.e. $(1,0,1,0,0,2...)$ and $(0,0,01,21,0,5...)$.

Yet the $df =368.586, t=2.2205, p=0.02699$, and the 95% confidence interval: $(0.1454645, 2.3970013)$.

The sample means are

```
Mean of x    mean of y
1.5452055.   0.2739726
```

Considering the df is larger than the amount of values I have I think it's gone wrong somewhere.

Comment: Read the manual (`t.test`). By default you're using the Welch-Satterthwaite approximation to the error degrees of freedom.

Comment: Plus, you have $2\times365 = 730$ observations, so the df do not exceed the amount of data you have. The pooled $t$ test will have 728 df, and since your Sattethwaite df are so much smaller, it suggests that there is a huge disparity between the sample variances. If so, you should not use the pooled $t$ anyway. I also wonder, given the familiarity of the number 365 and the equal sample sizes, is this really a paired-data situation? I.e., do you have daily measurements of the two species. If so, you should use a paired test. Again, see the documentation.

Comment: PS if you really have equal sample sizes, the pooled $t$ will be exactly the same value, just different df.

Comment: I doubt that a t-test is suitable here from several points of view: (i) It's *time series* data; you're unlikely to have the assumed independence; (ii) it looks like your data might actually be *counts* (they appear to be non-negative integers at least), not normally distributed random variables. What is the underlying research question you're trying to answer here?

Comment: The underlying question is whether there is any influence on migration of the fish, so I've got to compare, first off,if the two species of fish influence each other. The values are from daily measurements throughout the year so there are days that have no fish.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that the data you collected is normally distributed, as Glen_b notes.  Although $t$-tests are generally robust and somewhat tolerant of non-normality, highly skewed data (which is common for counts) will make such tests inappropriate.